# Visual Tkinter Python IDE doesn't work

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I just downloaded the Visual Tkinter Python IDE. Unfortunately, when I try to open new project it failed with this error:

[image: Unhandled exception error message]

[*Full size version*](http://gyazo.com/140900b3a0448298a504be9a87316e24)

I just read about this error and I found out that there may be a chance that my versions don't match.

My version of Python is 2.6 (32-bit). When I open a regular python Tkinter program and run it it works OK, but I don't know why in the IDE it dosen't work.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same problem with Python 2.7.12 (32-bit) and Visual Python 2.0.12.2524.